# What can we say about the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot (1-\cos(\frac{a}{n}))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion, limits-without-lhopital

Series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot (1-\cos(\frac{a}{n}))$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot(1-\cos(\frac{a}{n}))=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot[1- \{1-\frac{a^2}{2!\cdot n^2} + O(\frac{1}{n^4})\}] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^2}{2n} + O(\frac{1}{n^3})$$

Can we conclude with Limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1n$, that the given series is divergent?

Also can we say anything about its oscillatory nature?

Comment: This series is infact postive terms series. So I guess, it is indeed divergent from LCT with $\sum \frac1n$. Being a positive and divergent series, it can not be oscillatory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we have that

$$n\cdot\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\right)=\frac{a^2}{n}\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\right)}{\frac{a^2}{n^2}}\sim \frac{a^2}{2n}$$

then the series diverges by limit comparison test.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did writing it as $\frac{a^2}{n}\frac{\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{a}{n}\right)\right)}{\frac{a^2}{n^2}}$ help you conclude that it is similar to $\frac{a^2}{2n}$?

Comment: By standard limits $$(1-\cos x)/x^2\to \frac12$$

Comment: To the proposer:  $1-\cos x= 2\sin^2(x/2) \sim x^2/2$ as $x\to 0.$

Comment: @gimusi thank you

Comment: @SoLo You are welcome! Even if I don't understand the downvotes. Please do not hesitate to leave a comment if the answer can be improved in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, using
$\frac{2x}{\pi}
\le \sin(x)
\le x$
for
$0 \le x \le \pi/2$:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=1}^{m}n(1-\cos(\frac{a}{n}))
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}n(2\sin^2(\frac{a}{2n}))\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{m}n\sin^2(\frac{a}{2n})\\
&\ge 2\sum_{n=1}^{m}n(\frac{2a}{2\pi n})^2
\qquad\text{for }\frac{a}{2n} \le \frac{\pi}{2}
\text{ or }n \ge \frac{a}{\pi}  \\
&\ge 2\sum_{n=\lceil \frac{a}{\pi} \rceil}^{m}n(\frac{a}{\pi n})^2\\
&=\frac{2a^2}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=\lceil \frac{a}{\pi}\rceil}^{m}\frac1{n}\\
\end{array}
$

and this diverges
by comparison with
$\sum \frac1{n}$.